# Any good POS tagging websites?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I thought I had found one that was pretty good (Parts-of-speech.info), but I just entered the sentence "The kids hoot." and it told me "determiner noun noun." If it can't identify "hoot" as a verb...I can't really rely on it for anything.

Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

To elaborate: I'm using it to help me breakdown sentences in famous novels. Currently using Cormac McCarthy's "Blood Meridian," which has a lot of strange and interesting sentence constructions.

Comment: "Hoot" *is* a noun, though. As well as a verb. Words in English don't separate cleanly into distinct "part of speech" classes. Compared to other languages, English is more, er, duck-typed. It's no wonder algorithms have trouble determining which PoS role a word is playing in a given sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Link Grammar Parser](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/) is a syntactic parser of English, based on link grammar, an original theory of English syntax.

Enter ***The kids hoot***

Constituent tree:

(S (NP The kids)
(VP hoot))